# Can't get data from topic

Tags: ros, topic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am trying to get data from ar_pose_markers. I am running the package and I see the topic is refreshing with new data. I am using ar_tools and usb_cam.

I have to make a node that subscribe to this topic and it able to extract the information. I am subscribing to the topic but I can extract the position.  This code give me a number but is the same number all the time.

The node code is the following one

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/String.h"
#include <ar_pose/ARMarkers.h>



int yo=10;
int zo;
int i=0;
void ar_pose_markerCallback(const ar_pose::ARMarkers::ConstPtr& msg)
{
float xo=0;
ROS_INFO("hello world");
ar_pose::ARMarker ar_pose_marker;
xo=ar_pose_marker.pose.pose.orientation.x;
ROS_INFO("%d", xo);


}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
ROS_INFO("hello world");
ros::init(argc, argv, "node_sub");
ros::NodeHandle n;
ros::Rate loop_rate(1);
ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("ar_pose_marker", 1, ar_pose_markerCallback);
while (ros::ok())
```

{

```
ros::spinOnce();
loop_rate.sleep();
```

}
return 0;
}

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257807/can%27t-get-data-from-topic/) by [jsoley](https://answers.ros.org/users/29811/jsoley/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-03-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nlamprian](https://answers.ros.org/users/20033/nlamprian/) on 2017-03-24**:
Notice how you are not assigning anything with the received message `msg`.

**Comment by [saikishor](https://answers.ros.org/users/21247/saikishor/) on 2017-03-25**:
Yes!!! You are not using the message at all!!! You have just declared a variable with that type of message. Now, you try using the msg.

**Comment by [saikishor](https://answers.ros.org/users/21247/saikishor/) on 2017-03-29**:
Use this "msg->markers[0]" to fetch data in the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Man, like they say, use the msg to get the topic information. I can provide you some notes if you want.

---

Originally posted by [Brijesh GM](https://answers.ros.org/users/29820/brijesh-gm/) with karma: 16 on 2017-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0